# Disabling a linearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application , I am  dynamically generating two linearlayouts and adding them to ScrollView.

Each LinearLayout has a Button and an Edit Text, I want that when the Button of the second LinearLayout is clicked , the 1st Linearlayout gets disabled .

Code:

```
package com.integrated.mpr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Page1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    int i;
    int[][] id = new int[pos][3];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int p =0;
        Log.d("value of ", ""+pos);
        for(int i =0;i<2;i++){
            for(int j =0;j<3;j++){
                id[i][j] = p;
                p++;
            }
        }

        //In each row 1st column is the id for button
        //2nd column id for edittext
        //3rd column id for Linearlayout

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for(i=0;i<2;i++){

            LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);
            llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            llay.setId(id[i][2]);

            EditText et = new EditText(this);
            et.setId(id[i][1]);

            Button stop = new Button(this);
            stop.setText("Submit");
            stop.setId(id[i][0]);
            stop.setOnClickListener(this);

            llay.addView(et);
            llay.addView(stop);
            ll.addView(llay);

        }

        sv.addView(ll);
        this.setContentView(sv);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(v.getId()==id[1][0]){
            //when te second Button is clicked
            // now here disable the 1st linear layout
            //Can't think how to do it
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered keeping a reference to the Layout as a class member?

Comment: No , actually I have posted the question for two linear layouts , but actuallly in my app th e number of linearlayouts is variable , so no of class members wont be fixed as well

Comment: @kumer piyush: Have you considered an array or list?

Comment: I m trying to set the ids of linearlayous , buttons and edittext in array only , if u have a method plz do suggest

Comment: set your "view.setEnabled(false);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your LinearLayout and set it to View.GONE

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v.getId()==id[1][0]){
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(id);
        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    }
```

Comment: one problem the visibility gone is working But when i use ll.setEnabled(false) it doesnot get disabled.. what can be the reason?

Comment: Disabling a LinearLayout doesn't actually do anything. Disabling makes it so the user can't interact with the object, but they can still see it.

Comment: Exactly , Button even after still disabling the linealayout , its button gets clicked and the operation happens ,

Comment: Yes thats why you must either set your layout to GONE or you get the button and use button.setEnabled(false). You can't call disabled on the layout

Answer (score 0):

Keep the reference of your Layouts as a class member and in `OnClick` method set the `visibility` of layout as `View.GONE` for the layout you want to disable.

Comment: then what you want in disable mode "user cant take any action in the layout's child view"

Comment: Indeed, _user cant take any action_ but can still see the views.

Comment: then iterate all child view of the layout and `setEnable` as false.